# Inserting ID from combo box into SQL Server using VB.net

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, combobox

I have a VB form and a combobox linked to a datasource.

The database has two tables `Position` (`SLOT, ID_WH`) and `Warehouse` (`ID_WH, WH_NAME`).

The combobox is linked to the warehouse, and it shows the `WH_NAME`.

I need to get the `ID_WH` to insert into the `Position` table.

The code is:

```html
 WH_CB.DisplayMember = "Warehouse" 'Column name
       WH_CB.ValueMember = "ID_WH" 'Column name2


       'ADD INFO TO Position (SLOT)

       Dim Remove_space_start As String = SLOT_TXT.Text
       Dim CharStart() As Char = {" "}
       Dim Stringstart As String = Remove_space_start.TrimStart(CharStart)
       Dim CharEnd() As Char = {" "}
       Dim StringEnd As String = Stringstart.TrimEnd(CharEnd)

       Try
       objconnection.Open()
       cmd.Connection = objconnection

       cmd.CommandText = "InsertDataIntoPosition"
       cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure

       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SLOT", StringEnd)
       cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("ID_WH", WH_CB.SelectedValue)

       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

       MessageBox.Show("sucess")

       'Refresh DATAGRID
       dgv_slot.DataSource = Nothing
       dgv_slot.Refresh()

       Dim str As String = "select * from Position"

       Using cmd As New SqlCommand(str, objconnection)
       Using da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
       Using newtable As New DataTable
       da.Fill(newtable)
       dgv_slot.DataSource = newtable
       End Using
       End Using
       End Using

       Catch ex As Exception
       MessageBox.Show("Error while inserting record on table..." & 
       ex.Message, 
       "Insert Records")
       Finally
       objconnection.Close()
       End Try
```

I've tried to show the  whcb with a messagebox, and it shows the ID_WH, but trying to insert data into the table I get the error:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'Armazem4  ' to data type int.'

Any help?

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Still a working in progress, But will do that, as soon as I can get this error corrected.

Comment: @Xplode why not do it right the first time? Then you don't have to re-write. There's always a chance this error is related to the way you've written the query, as well. Anyway, I would guess that one of the fields "SLOT" or "ID_WH" is an integer field in the DB, and you're trying to insert a string value "Armazem4" into it. That's what the error is telling you.

Comment: That's the issue, the field is indeed int, but that why I'm using the:  `WH_CB.DisplayMember = "Warehouse" 'Column name
WH_CB.ValueMember = "ID_WH" 'Column name2

Dim whcb As Integer = WH_CB.SelectedValue` 

So I can get the ID_WH and insert that into the ID_WH field on the Position table.

Comment: You are not really listening here. The error says you are passing a string to an integer field. It doesn't matter what the data type of your whcb variable is. You can't pass a string to an int field in the database. Where is your query to return the WH_ID from the database? Most likely the issue is that SLOT is also integer field, and you are passing a string.

Comment: **SLOT** is a nchar field, The datasoure from the combobox is the warehouse table, so, its showing the WH_NAME, but on the Whcb is getting the ID_WH, and it got that info, because if I use `Messagebox.show(whcb)` its shows 8, thats the correct ID_WH , so when inserting it should insert the ID_WH, not the WH_name. That is why I'm not getting why its inserting **Armazem4** instead of **8**

Comment: if ID_WH in the DB is an int, then don't wrap the value you're inserting it to in quotes. `'" & whcb & "'` - remove the single quotes, otherwise that makes it look like a string. If you'd used parameterised queries then that error at least would be gone. Anyway set a breakpoint and check the value of whcb at the exact moment you put it into the INSERT statement.

Comment: OK, I've edit the code, and add the params, still happing the same. When I add the data it shows the SUCESS message, but after that, When I reopen the form, same error.

Also, If I go directly to the Table Data, The information is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's solved, thank you very much.

I had the same field name (with different types) in different tables, So I was forcing the wrong one to get the information.

After I corrected that, its working fine.